# DataContextChanged event of CheckBox

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-2.0

I am working in Silverlight4 VS 2010.I have placed a CheckBox in my .xaml file. I need it's DataContextChanged event. But unfortunately i didn't find it.

Here is my CheckBox :

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkRegion" Content="{Binding name}" Click="CheckBox_Click" ></CheckBox>
```

Could you please help me in to find DataContextChanged  in SL 4 VS 2010.

Thanks, Rajbir

Comment: What you are looking after to do so you need DataContextChanged event , if you can tell what you want to do .

Comment: I want to implement some logic in this event on the basis of that i can change the ischecked property of this checkbox. Actually this checkbox is placed in the DataTemplate of a Combobox.

Comment: Then why dont you use IValueConverter and bind it to your IsChecked property of an Checkbox in datatemplate. If you want me to write piece of code example that can help you let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement an Converter (its just a simple class which gets derived from IValueConverter and implement the interface methods)

> ```
> public class ChangeIsCheckedValConverter : IValueConverter
> {
>     public object Convert(object value,
>                           Type targetType,
>                           object parameter,
>                           System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
>     {
>         if (value != null)
>         {
> ```
>
> //value here is the object which you are binding to the DataContext of
>   Checkbox  ; //return the bool (true or false) based on your valued
>   binded to your checkbox
>
> ```
>     }
>
>     public object ConvertBack(object value,
>                               Type targetType,
>                               object parameter,
>                               System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
>     {
>         return null;
>     }
> ```

```
You will have to add the name space of you newly implemnted converter whereever you will want to use .
```

Then use this converter where your checkbox is defined in datatemplate  as below :
//First define the key as below :

```
 <converters:VisibilityConverter x:Key="changeConverter" />

<CheckBox x:Name="chkRegion" Content="{Binding name}" IsChecked={Binding ,Converter={StaticResource changeConverter}}"} Click="CheckBox_Click" ></CheckBox>
```